# Does A/B testing in Laravel (and general) require a kind of dashboard, where different A/B test can be started and so called managed?

Tags: laravel, ab-testing, abtest

I am just getting in touch with A/B testing, and I have some problems to understand it. As far as I understood so far, A/B testing needs some front-end variations, that should be evaluated based on visitors's behaviour on the pages. When A/B testing starts, every visitors get a page variant, based on a logic, like 30% of visitors get version A, and 70% of visitors get version B on average. My question is, that how I start the test itself? If the visitor on the page, how can I detect behaviour, for example if a button is clicked and how many times?

I want to implement my own A/B testing tool, a simply one only. I have found any throughout tutorial on this topic sofar.

Comment: Interactions are normally tracked by Google Analytics.
However you could ofcourse track these yourself in JS.
It depends on your use-case I suppose..